# "Объединенный" вывод

Tags: c++, char, radstudio

Как можно вывести объединенный вывод?

Ибо

```
Memo1->Lines->Add(cmp+" "+tmp2+"-"+tmp1);
```

не работает.

```
char tmp1, tmp2;
char cmp[] = "Сравнение";
Form3->Memo1->Lines->Add("Начало сравнения: ");
for (int i = 1; i <= middle; i++)
{
    tmp1 = one.top();
    one.pop();
    tmp2 = two.top();
    two.pop();
    strcat(cmp, " ", tmp2);
    Form3->Memo1->Lines->Add(cmp+" "+tmp2+"-"+tmp1);
    if (tmp1 != tmp2)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Объявления складываемых переменных с типами покажи.

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил в тему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> strcat(cmp, " ", tmp2);
> Form3->Memo1->Lines->Add(cmp+" "+tmp2+"-"+tmp1);
> ```

Замени на:

```
char temp[256];
sprintf(temp, "%s %c-%c", cmp, tmp2, tmp1);
Form3->Memo1->Lines->Add(temp);
```

Comment: Отлично, это то, что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: @DesmondFox, дефис вместо второго пробела, чтоб совсем как ты хотел было.

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует использовать какой-нибудь класс для строк, который имеет оператор конкатенации +.

Например, вы могли бы использовать стандартный класс `std::string` определенный в заголовке `<string>`

```
std::string cmp = "Сравнение";
```

И вместо этих предложения

```
strcat(cmp, " ", tmp2);
Form3->Memo1->Lines->Add(cmp+" "+tmp2+"-"+tmp1);
```

записать

```
cmp += ' ';
cmp += tmp2;

Form3->Memo1->Lines->Add( ( cmp + ' ' + tmp2 + '-' + tmp1 ).c_str() );
```